# How to do request for iOS installed app to accessing authentication code for google authentication

Tags: iphone, authorization, google-authentication

Here is what I have done in my process and what else i need please let me know .

1. I registered my iPhone app at google console and got client id, and secret id .
2. add url type as AB.MyGoogleAppLogin(Ab-bundle identifier, MyGoogleAppLogin - name of registered app) in info.plist .
3. My app is not at web or at local host, its present locally in my mac .
4. Using web view in my app and also include protocol at interface .

How do i get my authorization code and where do I get it from? .

Please help me out .
Thank you